# Clarification on the Ending of Soul of the Fire

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

I finished *Soul of the Fire* from Terry Goodkind's *Sword of Truth* series and I have to say that I'm a little confused about the ending, specifically the whole part about Joseph Ander. What I understand is:

- Richard realizes that the Dominie Dirtch was created by Joseph Ander and they are somehow powered by the Chimes (and they have worked ever since then).
- He deduces from Joseph Ander's diary that in his madness he figured out how to trap himself alone in a realm outside of the living and the dead, effectively preserving him for 3,000 years since he couldn't enter the Underworld
- That realm was physically located (or somehow connected to) the swamp area and it's what wound up making it poisonous. I'm guessing that Joseph Ander created the moths that suck up the poison so that his beloved Anderith wouldn't be killed as a result.
- Richard uses his War Wizard instincts to create a non-traditional Grace to pull Joseph Ander back out of his realm. I think this cleans up the swamp, but I'm not sure it ever said.
- The Chimes are defeated when Richard tells them that they can either take his soul to the Underworld or Joseph Ander's. Apparently they can only take one, and they get to pick despite the fact that they were summoned by being promised Richard. They choose Joseph Ander and take him to the Underworld.
- The Dominie Dirtch quits working because the Chimes are back in the Underworld.

Did I understand everything correctly? Particularly, did I understand the connection between Joseph Ander's realm and the swamp?

Also, could someone explain why the Dominie Dirtch quit working? I get that the Chimes went back to the Underworld, but weren't they already there before Kahlan summoned them? I'm guessing that Joseph Ander being in his own realm was part of the equation and with him no longer there, that's why they quit working, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Sword of Truth Wikia](http://sot.wikia.com/wiki/Chimes_of_Doom#History) (there's more in the wiki, but if you haven't read beyond Soul of the Fire there's some spoiler information there):

> The chimes were released sometime around the Great War, though they
>   were defeated by Joseph Ander. Ander in fact entrapped the chimes into
>   an artifact known as the Dominie Dirtch which he surrounded around the
>   land of Anderith as a means of defence against intruders.
>
> ...
>
> However, Richard Rahl ultimately discovered what Joseph Ander had done
>   thousands of years ago, and was able to convince the chimes to consume
>   the spirit of the man who had entombed them; in the process causing
>   them to leave the world of the living, and instead take Joseph Ander's
>   soul to the Underworld, trapping themselves for the sake of revenge.

Comment: That seems to describe most of what I know. So when Kahlan summoned the chimes, they were pulled out of the Dominie Dirtch rather than out of the Underworld? That doesn't seem consistent with the part where Zedd tries to offer himself to them and then the Dominie Dirtch goes off out of their anger because they still had a connection to it. You mentioned there was spoiler information, so are the remaining questions (plus the deal about the swamp) answered in future books?

Answer (score 1):

### You've got a solid grasp on a lot of the end results, with some muddied bits about the relevance of the swamp.

> • Richard realizes that the Dominie Dirtch was created by Joseph Ander and they are somehow powered by the Chimes (and they have worked ever since then).

Correct.

> • He deduces from Joseph Ander's diary that in his madness he figured out how to trap himself alone in a realm outside of the living and the dead, effectively preserving him for 3,000 years since he couldn't enter the Underworld

I would argue contempt and vanity over madness. He was ordered to deal with the chimes. Instead, he opted to:

- create a civilization that gives him the credit he deserves
- achieve the closest thing to immortality hitherto obtained by a wizard
- enslave a handful of evil spirits that terrified everyone else in existence.

> • That realm was physically located (or somehow connected to) the swamp area and it's what wound up making it poisonous. I'm guessing that Joseph Ander created the moths that suck up the poison so that his beloved Anderith wouldn't be killed as a result.

"The Ovens" were an area that naturally enhanced magic, making Ander's approach to "magic as an art form" more effective. The Ovens happen to exist behind a waterfall. Before the water plunges over the edge, it passes through a bunch of vines of the paku plant (IIRC) which remove the poison from the water.

> • Richard uses his War Wizard instincts to create a non-traditional Grace to pull Joseph Ander back out of his realm. I think this cleans up the swamp, but I'm not sure it ever said.

Richard draws himself a *fatal grace* in order to create the magic required to beat Ander at his own game. He calls the chimes to himself, and they come to consume his soul... (this step does nothing to the swamp)

> • The Chimes are defeated when Richard tells them that they can either take his soul to the Underworld or Joseph Ander's. Apparently they can only take one, and they get to pick despite the fact that they were summoned by being promised Richard. They choose Joseph Ander and take him to the Underworld.

...However, being in the fatal grace with the magic he artfully created, he would take Joseph Ander's position and the chimes would be bound to his will. Richard offers the chimes the choice to kill their enslaver instead, and they do just that, freeing them from their bonds to the Dominie Dirtch.

> • The Dominie Dirtch quits working because the Chimes are back in the Underworld.

Richard (paraphrase) offers the chimes Joseph Ander's soul, stripped bare. The chimes kill Joseph Ander and destroy the magic binding them to the Dominie Dirtch in the process. The Dominie Dirtch crumble. The chimes exist in the underworld regardless of being bound to the Dominie Dirtch - the bells are just a unique additional duty that Joseph Ander stuck them with through his unique approach to problem solving.

**Everything about the swamp that other answers neglect**
Richard, knowing all of Anderith to be a lost cause, uses his end-of-the-book, therefore awesome-magic-time power to rip out the front of the Cliffside over which the waterfall plunges. This tears apart the vegetation choke point, resulting in a river of poisonous water going through Anderith. Richard does this with the intent to give Jagang/the Imperial Order "a belly ache." given that they took the bread basket of the Midlands.

We later learn that the poison was mostly diluted when the river merged with other bodies of water, and the effect was minimal.

Answer (score 0):

The Dominie Dirtch were linked to the Chimes. Once the chimes returned to the underworld, that link was broken as it could not pass through the veil. This isn't actually explained, but is how I understand it from how magic works in Sword of Truth.

The chimes couldn't go back to the underworld previously because they had been bound to the Dominie Dirtch. They still weren't free after Kalahn released them, as they were bound by Joseph Ander's spell to seek out a specific individual. In this case, Richard.

Had the chimes killed Richard, Joseph Ander's spell would kick back in, and the chimes would be bound back to the Dominie Dirtch.